# Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module, change type doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, import, module, typeerror

I wanted to test this example in my own environment: https://github.com/shybovycha/gantt-chart.

I have an example.ejs:

```
<body>
...
  <script text="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

gantt-chart.js:

```
import {
    addMilliseconds,
    getDayOfYear,
    startOfDay,
    format as formatDate,
    min as minDate,
    max as maxDate
} from 'date-fns';
...
export class GanttChart extends EventTarget {
..}
```

index.js:

```
import {
    startOfDay,
    add as addDuration
} from 'date-fns';

import { GanttChart } from './gantt-chart';
...
```

I installed date-fns with `npm i date-fns`, it is listed in my package.json as dependency.
I already tried changing the script tag in example.js to `<script type="module" src="/javascripts/index.js"></script>` which resulted in error: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "date-fns". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

What am I doint wrong?

Comment: *"date-fns". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".*

Comment: @appleapple Fixing this results in: The resource from "http://localhost:3000/node_modules/date-fns" was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff). "The resource from"http://localhost:3000/javascripts/gantt-chart" was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).